# Split one Powershell command over multiple lines when using in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

This command works to replace instances of `OldText1`, `OldText2` and `OldText3` in a txt file, with `NewText1`, `NewText2` and `NewText3` when the command is on one line in a batch file like so:

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem 'Old and New text.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace 'OldText1', 'NewText1' -replace 'OldText2', 'NewText2' -replace 'OldText3', 'NewText3' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

If I try to use the `^` symbol to split the command up (that typically works in a batch file) it doesn't work. For example this doesn't work, nothing is replaced in the txt file:

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem 'Old and New text.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) ^
-replace 'OldText1', 'NewText1' ^
-replace 'OldText2', 'NewText2' ^
-replace 'OldText3', 'NewText3' ^
| Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

Using backticks also doesn't work (but it wouldn't because this is not a PS1 script):

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem 'Old and New text.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) `
-replace 'OldText1', 'NewText1' `
-replace 'OldText2', 'NewText2' `
-replace 'OldText3', 'NewText3' `
| Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

I have been asking that chat bot thing all morning and it can't come up with anything that works. Half the time it keeps putting the command on one line again and I'm just going around in circles with it.

Is it impossible to do what I am trying to do?

The reason I want to split the command over multiple lines is simply because I want to be able to read what's being replaced without having to look horizontally along (what will eventually be) a massive command. I intend to add far more replace commands than this, but it's not working even for three replace commands... yet!

Thanks in advance to anyone that might know why this isn't working.

Comment: Try to use the caret syntax, but enclose each line in its own double-quotes (`"`).

Comment: Thanks but that won't work.

Comment: See also: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69438245/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not clear to me:

> ***`Get-ChildItem 'Old and New text.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_)`***

This part suggests that you are going to get items in a folder, precisely items that are files, but immediately your command defines a file where the string replacements will be done right in the content.

See, by removing that part, the replacements came out as expected, but if this is for multiple files for the same replacements, then I'd suggest editing the question. Although confusing, for content handling you don't need "`Get-ChildItem 'Old and New text.txt' | ...`", and you can directly use `Get-Content 'Old and New text.txt' ^|...`

```ps1
start "Start PS1/CMD" /wait /min PowerShell.exe -c  ^
"$Strings=Get-Content 'Old And New Text.txt' ^| %%  ^
   ^{ $_ -replace('OldText1','NewText1')^
         -replace('OldText2','NewText2')^
         -replace('OldText3','NewText3')^}^
  ; sc 'Old And New Text.txt' -Value $Strings -Force"
```

Comment: Yep, that does work. Thanks for resolving this. The confusing bit: I just left the command how it was, from using "*.txt" in the past. I put the actual name of the file I was trying it on and left `Get-ChildItem` there because I'm lazy (and stupid when it comes to Powershell haha).

Comment: At least in (my) W10, you also don't need the foreach: `(gc 'file') -replace('a','x') -replace('b','y') ... | sc 'file'` (with linebreaks to taste)

Comment: @mklement0 I agree with that:  *"As such, letting **`-Ex -By`** stand is a bad example that can confuse others*" thanks!